# Command to edit redis hash value

Tags: node.js, redis

In my redis database I have data in following structure:

```
Folder(gk)
  Folder(integration)
    Folder(apifactory)
      key(gk:integration:apifactory:mobile)
```

The key has the hashkey and hashvalue in the following structure:

```
 Hashkey                   HashValue
 endPointTieout              5
```

Now I want to change this value(5) to some other value. What's the command to edit the value?

I also tried:

```
HMSET gk:integration:apifactory:mobile field1 "endPointTimeout" field2 "90"
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you misread the Redis documentation. `field1` isn't a literal name, it's a place holder for the name of your field. In your case, you would do:

```
HMSET gk:integration:apifactory:mobile endPointTimeout 5 some_other_field "some_value"
```

Or, if you just have one field (as it seems like you do):

```
HSET gk:integration:apifactory:mobile endPointTimeout 5
```